# Total War: Warhammer II, Can every faction win the vortex race?

Tags: warhammer-ii-total-war

Although the game isn't out a lot of people have gotten early keys and are allowed to play. So I started wondering are only the 4 playable factions able to race for domination over the vortex or are the non-playabe faction able too as well? If this question is somehow not answerable (due to it no being fully released) I will close it.

Comment: I don't know the answer but if its not answerable due to not yet released its probably easier just to leave it for the two/three days until it is released - its not like its months til general release...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out only the major factions (The player) and the remaining 3 others main ones can work towards claiming victory using the vortex.

This means situation

Player is High Elves,

- Mazdamundi for lizardman
- Malekith for dark elves
- Queek for Skaven

In Case One of the 4 Major factions gets confederated this faction will then takeover the race for the vortex. Here are the scenario's:

- Order of Loremasters confederates  Lothren
- Naggarond gets confederated by the Cult of Pleasure
- Hexoatl gets confederated by Last Defenders
- Clan Mors get confederated by Clan Pestillence

Comment: In my first campaign Morathi's Cult of Pleasure had managed to confederate Malekith's Naggarond. From then on it was Morathi that was conducting the rituals for the dark elves.

Comment: @MonkeezOnFire I will add this to complete the answer